# Using .net interface in matlab

Tags: .net, matlab

I have tried to use the ETABS dll file in MATLAB. The documentation explains how to use the dll file in .net languages. By changing the code I can use it in matlab, but there is some error.

My code:

```
 asm = NET.addAssembly('C:\Program Files\Computers and Structures\ETABS 2013\ETABS2013.dll')
 ETABSAssembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom('C:\Program Files\Computers and Structures\ETABS 2013\ETABS.exe')
 ETABSObject = ETABSAssembly.CreateInstance('CSI.ETABS.API.ETABSObject')
```

and the output for the last line is:

```
ETABSObject = 

  CSI.ETABS.API.ETABSObject handle with no properties.
  Package: CSI.ETABS.API

  Methods, Events, Superclasses


Superclasses for class CSI.ETABS.API.ETABSObject:

    System.MarshalByRefObject
    System.Object
    handle
    ETABS2013.cOAPI
```

after that I must convert the object to `ETABS2013.cOAPI` which is a abstract class, by using the cast operator as follows:

```
a = cast(ETABSObject,ETABS2013.cOAPI)
```

But I get the following error:

```
??? Error using ==> ETABS2013.cOAPI
Creating an instance of the Abstract class 'ETABS2013.cOAPI' is not allowed.
```

How to convert the Etabs object to cOAPI?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think [cast](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cast.html) does what you are trying to do. It only works on built-in data types.

I also don't think you can cast to `ETABS2013.cOAPI` using any technique. Abstract classes are [abstract](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf985hc5.aspx); you can't have an object of that type.